# Python - How to Align Axis in import image as plane?

Tags: python, scripting

I am scripting an addon to help with workflow and I cannot get the align_axis() param of the import image as the plane to work. It always aligns it to the main axis, I am trying to get it to align to a Z+ (So up.)

```
bpy.ops.import_image.to_plane(files=[{"name":scenename+".png", "name":scenename+".png"}], directory=filepath, shader="SHADELESS", align_axis="Z+")
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I cannot work out what I am doing wrong.

All the best.

Comment: Could you add a picture of result and expected result for one imported image. AFAICT this is working OK it aligns the normal of plane to the global z axis.

Comment: Actually... It is working now, I guess I just needed to restart blender. Whoops. Rookie mistake, Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code works as intended. Just had to restart blender for change to my script to take effect.

Comment: Oh ok, in 2.79x F8 key would reload scripts via operator `bpy.ops.scripts.reload()`  can remake the shortcut, call this in python console, or append a button for it say in text editor header to avoid having to close/restart blender for every addon edit.  (will depend somewhat on error and how you import in addon, see how a lot of addons use `imp.reload`)